# React loader/spinner whenever a function is called

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function as follows:

```js
const saveFile = () => {
    const curState = getState().sheet;
    const cropData = calImgCrop(curState);

    html2canvas(document.querySelector("#grid-container"), {
      x: cropData.xOffset,
      y: cropData.yOffset,
      width: cropData.width,
      height: cropData.height,
    }).then(canvas => {
      downloadFile(canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 0.5), 'result.png');
    });

    const state = {
      scale: curState.scale,
      text: curState.text,
      objects: curState.objects,
      walls: curState.walls
    };
    const compressedJSON = LZUTF8.compress(JSON.stringify(state));
    dispatch(loadFile(
      JSON.parse(LZUTF8.decompress(compressedJSON))
    ));
  }
```

the function is quite time consuming and I would like to add a loading spinner to this whenever it gets called. I'm very new to React and I'm not sure how should I do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Also if there's any more information required, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can dispatch an action that signals the beginning of loading at the start of the function. Your reducer can process that action to set some `loading` state. Make sure you also set `loading` to false when the asynchronous operations complete. Your component can read that `loading` state, and render a spinner when appropriate.

You may want to check out [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/) which is a middleware for redux designed to help with flows like this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use if-else statement for render loading like this

```
if(!x){

  <loading/>

 } else {

  <mainView/>
}
```

x is the response to your request